# MLPRegressor with partial_fit()

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

I'm using a `MLPRegressor()` with `partial_fit()`. My dataset has 2 outputs and 2 inputs.
I'm using a sequential model:

```
# input: X.shape(10.000, 2)
# output: y.shape(10.000, 2)
model = MLPRegressor()

for i in range(len(X)):
    model.partial_fit(X[i], y[i])
    # more code
```

But it gives me this error at `model.partial_fit(X[i], y[i])`:

```
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

What's the problem? How could I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial fit operates on a subset of `X` and `y`. Right now you're using a single row, but those don't have the expected shape. If you want to pass data in one point at a time you just need some way to let scikit-learn know that you have a single data point. Here's a couple options.

```
# Your current strategy
# model.partial_fit(X[i], y[i])
# Doesn't work because X[i] and y[i] have shape (2,) rather than (1, 2)

# Slices
model.partial_fit(X[i:i+1], y[i:i+1])

# Reshape
model.partial_fit(X[i].reshape(1, -1), y[i].reshape(1, -1))
```

Alternatively, you could use the same method to operate in larger batches (or apply masks, or do any of a number of other things -- it's pretty flexible).

```
n = 2
for i in range(0, len(X), n):
    model.partial_fit(X[i:i+n], y[i:i+n])
```